# Dojo EnhancedGrid & Store : Why isn't the options.count set when the filter is on?

Tags: javascript, dojo

I use dojox/grid/EnhancedGrid. When the table calls the `query()` method from the `store` while filtering, the `options.count` is unset. Is there any reason behind this behaviour? I want to still be able to limit the result while filtering.

Comment: If the grid has pagination enabled, maybe it's left to the plugin to choose the value of `count`.

Comment: can you rephrase your answer please?

Comment: If the grid has enabled the pagination plugin, I think it's its [the plugin] job to define the number of records, to be queried. That way it can provide proper pagination.

Comment: Ok so you're saying that pagination plugin is the one that is responsible for this? Any reason why it does that? What does it has anything to do with the filter? Its job is to limit the result right? It doesn't even set the `count`. It should mark the `count` variable as `Infinity` instead.

Comment: It was just a hunch. I haven't check the source to conform if it's true. Can you provide a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) of your situation, so all the details are clear.

Comment: I can't make a fiddle of it since I have a custom dojo class, but it's easy for you to just edit the JsonRest store to see that the options.count isn't set when filtering.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out I need to turn `isServerSide: true` for this to work properly. Because otherwise Dojo will try to filter out the result on the client side and it requests all the data available instead which is why the `options.count` isn't set.

My reference : [dojox.grid.EnhancedGrid.plugins.Filter](https://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.9/dojox/grid/EnhancedGrid/plugins/Filter.html)